# Prove/Disprove: $v$ is an eigenvector of $T^n$ implies $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, examples-counterexamples

> Prove/Disprove: $v$ is an eigenvector of $T^n$ implies $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$

I'm pretty sure it's not necessarily true, but can't think of a counter example.

Can you help me think of one?

Comment: This result is intimately connected to the diagonalizability of $T$.

Comment: @GitGud, for both $n=1,2$ the only eigenvalue is $0$. I don't get it.

Comment: @AlonAlon Check Pavel's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The matrix
$$
T=\pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$
has a one-dimensional eigenvector space spanned by $[1,0]^T$, but any 2-vector is an eigenvector of $T^2=0$.

Comment: I like this one because it works on any field.

Comment: But, $\det(\lambda I - T) = \lambda^2 = 0 \implies \lambda = 0$.

Comment: @AlonAlon Why would that be a problem?

Comment: Oh I see now, it's not a problem!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**  Take $T$ the rotation of angle $\frac{2\pi}n$.

Comment: Does not work for $n=2$.